# Inheritance hierarchy altering to reduce code duplication

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, hierarchy

I'm experiencing difficulties setting up the structure of my code. In one project, I have two classes `LeftCell` and `RightCell`, both extending class `Cell`. Now, to avoid code duplication, I want to use these objects in multiple other projects. The problem is that I also want to add extra functionalities to these objects (the `Cell` object in particular), which differ per project.

Suppose I create a new project in which I want to visualize `Cell` objects using a `void draw()` method. My first thought was to create a new `CellProject1` class that extends the `Cell` class and includes the `draw()` method:

```
class CellProject1 extends Cell {
    void draw() {}
}
```

The problem is that any `LeftCell`/`RightCell` objects I create, do of course not have access to this `draw()` method. I guess I want to somehow squeeze a `Cell` subclass in the class hierarchy such that it changes from:

```
Cell
    LeftCell
    RightCell
```

to:

```
Cell
    CellProjectX
        LeftCell
        RightCell
```

depending on the project I'm running. I played around with generics, but can't get it to work. All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that any LeftCell/RightCell objects I create, do of
>   course not have access to this  draw() method.

A method specific to a child class can not of course be invoked on a parent instance that doesn't know it.

Since your requirement is

> Inheritance hierarchy altering to reduce code duplication
>   In one project, I have two classes LeftCell and RightCell, both
>   extending class Cell.
>   Now, to avoid code duplication, I want to use these objects in
>   multiple other projects

I think that you should make things a little different.

If  you want to avoid exploding the number of combination possible of classes and not duplicating `LeftCell` and `RightCell` like in your example :

```
Cell
    CellProjectX
        LeftCell
        RightCell
```

that could be finally completed by  :

```
Cell
    CellProjectY
        LeftCell
        RightCell

Cell
    CellProjectZ
        LeftCell
        RightCell
```

you should favor the composition over the inheritance to create your specific project `Cell` implementations.

**For the common Cell structures:**

The `Cell` subclass could be a `Cell` interface that define common methods for any `Cell` and you could have a `AbstractCell` class that defines common implementation for it.

```
public interface Cell{
   int getValue();
   void setValue(int value);
}


public abstract class AbstractCell implements Cell{
      ...
}
```

Then you could define the `RightCell` and `LeftCell` by extending `AbstractCell` :

```
public class RightCell extends AbstractCell {
      ...
}

public class LeftCell extends AbstractCell {
      ...
}
```

**For the Cell implementations specific to a project :**

Now in a specific project you could a create a custom `Cell` implementation by composing it with a `Cell` instance (finally a `LeftCell` or `RightCell` instance) that will under the hood be used to implement the `Cell` interface in the specific project concrete class.
In the specific implementation, you could of course add any required method specific to the project.
For example :

```
class CellProject1 implements Cell {

   private Cell cell;

   CellProject1 (Cell cell){
      this.cell = cell;
   }

   public int getValue(){
      cell.getValue();
   } 

   public void setValue(int value){
      cell.setValue(value);
   }

   public void draw(){
   ...
   }

}
```

You can so create `CellProject1` instances like that :

```
CellProject1 leftCell = new CellProject1(new LeftCell());
CellProject1 rightCell = new CellProject1(new RightCell());
leftCell.draw();
rightCell.draw();
```

And in another project that uses `CellProject2` instances with a specific `write()`method, you could write :

```
CellProject2 leftCell = new CellProject2(new LeftCell());
CellProject2 rightCell = new CellProject2(new RightCell());
leftCell.write();
rightCell.write();
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I also want to add extra functionalities to these objects (the Cell object in particular), which differ per project.

I recommend creating an interface that `Cell` implements, allowing its child classes to implement the methods that you want, especially if `Cell` is an abstract class.

```
public interface Features {
    ...
}

public abstract class Cell implements Features {
    ...
}
```